# Salesforce SDK for iOS for Partner Communities

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, partner-communities, offline

Is it possible to build a Salesforce Mobile SDK iOS app that allows Partner Community users to login to the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can always have Community Users to be able to login to any native/hybrid iOS app that you build. It depends on how you want to build your app and who are the target users, but in general there is no dependency of a native/hybrid app that cannot be used for Community Users.

You can find more details on [Salesforce Communities and Mobile SDK Apps](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/communities_mobilesdk.htm?search_text=community). In summary, what you need here is:

- Make sure that each community member has the API Enabled permission. You can set this permission through profiles or permission sets.
- Configure your community to include your API-enabled profiles and permission sets.
- Configure your Mobile SDK app to use your community’s login endpoint.